PHPUnit fails on Jenkins agent pod (k3s) but works in Docker container
My apologies for the length of the question.  I am trying to be as thorough as possible.
Summary:
I am totally new to PHPUnit testing and I want to build Jenkins CI pipelines for my projects that perform PHPUnit testing.  The PHPUnit tests run fine in a local Docker container in Windows but fail when running in a Jenkins agent pod in my Kubernetes cluster.
Facts:

I have a K3S cluster made up of several Raspberry Pi 4B (ARM64 architecture).
The test is successful in my Windows machine using Docker (x64 architecture).
Code is identical in both places.
Running PHP 8.1 and PHPUnit 10.1.0

Background:
The Approach:
When reading this article by Bob Allen, it sounded like the best way for me to run my PHPUnit tests.  I already have a Kubernetes cluster and Jenkins running in it.  I can just build a docker image that contains all the necessary requirements to perform the PHPUnit tests and kill it when done, eliminating the need to have a dedicated machine for that.
I created the agent image and built it for ARM64 and x64 systems.  Dockerfile included for reference.  The same Dockerfile was used to create both images, the only difference is the processor architecture.
    FROM php:8.1.19-fpm-alpine

    WORKDIR /tmp

    RUN apk --no-cache add \
        ca-certificates \
        # We need composer to set up PHPUnit
        composer \
        linux-headers \
        # Add dependencies for PHP 8.1
        php81-bcmath \
        php81-calendar \
        php81-ctype \
        php81-curl \
        php81-dom \
        php81-exif \
        php81-fileinfo \
        php81-json \
        php81-mbstring \
        php81-mysqli \
        php81-opcache \
        php81-openssl \
        php81-pcntl \
        php81-pdo \
        php81-pdo_dblib \
        php81-pdo_mysql \
        php81-pdo_odbc \
        php81-pdo_pgsql \
        php81-pdo_sqlite \
        php81-pecl-memcache \
        php81-phar \
        php81-session \
        php81-simplexml \
        php81-soap \
        php81-tokenizer \
        php81-xdebug \
        php81-xml \
        php81-xmlreader \
        php81-xmlwriter \
        php81-zip \
        php81-zlib \
    # We also use PEAR
    && php -r "copy('https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar', 'go-pear.phar');" \
    && php go-pear.phar \
    && php -r "unlink('go-pear.phar');"

    # Install PHPUnit 10.1.0 using composer
    RUN composer require "phpunit/phpunit:10.1.0" --prefer-source --no-interaction \
    && composer require "phpunit/php-invoker" --prefer-source --no-interaction \
    # Install into /usr/local/bin/phpunit
    && ln -s /tmp/vendor/bin/phpunit /usr/local/bin/phpunit \
    # Add name to PHPUnit providers
    && sed -i 's/nn and/nn, Jorge Pabón, and/g' /tmp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/Version.php

    # Install X-Debug
    RUN apk --no-cache add pcre-dev ${PHPIZE_DEPS} \ 
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && apk del pcre-dev ${PHPIZE_DEPS} \
    # Configure X-Debug
    && echo "xdebug.start_with_request=yes" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.mode=coverage" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.log=/App/xdebug.log" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.discover_client_host=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_port=9000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

    WORKDIR /App

    ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]

To test my image, I deployed it locally using Docker, mounted the directory that contains a simple app, and ran the PHPUnit test manually.  It was successful.

I also built the ARM64 image that would be used by my K3S cluster in my x64 machine using Docker's Buildx and ran it.  It was successful.

Now, I moved to doing the same but using a Jenkins agent in my Kubernetes cluster.
Preparation:
I created a Jenkinsfile to define the pipeline so far.  (Can't write it directly because the website is complaining about the markup and I can't figure it out.)
NOTE: For the sake of this question, I made the repository public but it was originally private.
The repository file structure is as follows:
Test
|  app
    |  SodaMachine.php
|  CI
    |  Jenkinsfile
|  tests
    |  SodaMachineTest.php
|  autoload.php
|  composer.json
|  phpunit.xml

NOTE: I had to do a little bit of file reorganizing because, to clone the private repository, it would put the 'Test' folder that I didn't need.  In the end, I get the same structure as I did locally with Docker.
Here are the contents of the files in the repository:
app/SodaMachine.php:
    <?php

    namespace App;

    class SodaMachine {

      // Variables
      private $cans;

      // Methods

      // Returns the amount of cans in the machine
      public function getCans(){
        return $this->cans;
      }

      // Fill the machine to the specified amount of cans
      public function setCans( $amount ){
        $this->cans = $amount;
      }

      // Processes a can purchase
      public function buyCan(){
        $this->setCans( $this->getCans() - 1 );
      }

    }

    ?>

tests/SodaMachineTest.php
    <?php

    // Use the same namespace as the app
    namespace App;

    require '/App/app/SodaMachine.php';

    /**
     * @covers \App\SodaMachine
    */
    class SodaMachineTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase{
      // Variables
  
      // Define an instance of the Soda Machine
      public $sodaMachine;

      // Functions

      // Instantiate the machine (make sure to mark it returns void or PHPUnit complains)
      public function setUp(): void {
        $this->sodaMachine = new SodaMachine();
      }
  
      /**
       * Test the machine functionality
       * @covers \App\SodaMachine::buyCan
      */
      public function testCanPurchase(){
        // Start with 10 cans
        $this->sodaMachine->setCans( 10 );
        // Buy a can
        $this->sodaMachine->buyCan();
        // Validate it processed it right and we have 9 left
        $this->assertEquals( 9, $this->sodaMachine->getCans() );
      }
  
    }

    ?>

phpunit.xml:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!-- Define properties and behavior -->
    <phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/10.1/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="autoload.php"
         cacheDirectory=".phpunit.cache"
         executionOrder="depends,defects"
         requireCoverageMetadata="true"
         beStrictAboutCoverageMetadata="true"
         beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
         failOnRisky="true"
         failOnWarning="false"
         colors="true"
         stopOnFailure="false">

      <!-- Specify the Test Suites -->
      <testsuites>
        <!-- Name and location of the Test Suite to perform -->
        <testsuite name="Soda Machine Tests">
          <!-- Path is relative to the location of this config file -->
          <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
      </testsuites>

      <!-- Specify Test Coverage -->
      <source restrictDeprecations="true" restrictNotices="true" restrictWarnings="true">
        <include>
          <!-- Cover all PHP files in the app folder -->
          <!-- Path is relative to the location of this config file -->
          <directory suffix=".php">app</directory>
        </include>
      </source>
  
    </phpunit>

autoload.php: (is blank but it was complaining because it is defined in the phpunit.xml)
<?php

?>

composer.json: (not sure if it is even necessary)
{
  "require":{
      "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1.0"
  },
  
  "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
          "App\\": "app"
      }
  }
}

The problem:
When I trigger my Pipeline, the PHPUnit tests run but I have to specify the path for PHPUnit to be /App instead of '.'.  I get the following:
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Created Pod: K3S devops-tools/test-103-nr8m3-4xklv-nplz3
Agent test-103-nr8m3-4xklv-nplz3 is provisioned from template Test_103-nr8m3-4xklv
---
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
  annotations:
    buildUrl: "http://jenkins.devops-tools.svc.cluster.local:8080/job/Test/103/"
    runUrl: "job/Test/103/"
  labels:
    jenkins: "agent"
    jenkins/label-digest: "e36625b8c9189bcc484f60169fddec4e2453f785"
    jenkins/label: "Test_103-nr8m3"
  name: "test-103-nr8m3-4xklv-nplz3"
  namespace: "devops-tools"
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - "1d"
    command:
    - "sleep"
    image: "prengineer/jenkins-agent-php-8.1:ARM64"
    imagePullPolicy: "Always"
    name: "jenkins-php8-agent"
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
  - env:
    - name: "JENKINS_SECRET"
      value: "********"
    - name: "JENKINS_TUNNEL"
      value: "jenkins.devops-tools.svc.cluster.local:50000"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_NAME"
      value: "test-103-nr8m3-4xklv-nplz3"
    - name: "JENKINS_NAME"
      value: "test-103-nr8m3-4xklv-nplz3"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR"
      value: "/home/jenkins/agent"
    - name: "JENKINS_URL"
      value: "http://jenkins.devops-tools.svc.cluster.local:8080/"
    image: "jenkins/inbound-agent:3206.vb_15dcf73f6a_9-2"
    name: "jnlp"
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "256Mi"
        cpu: "100m"
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: "linux"
  restartPolicy: "Never"
  volumes:
  - emptyDir:
      medium: ""
    name: "workspace-volume"

Running on test-103-nr8m3-4xklv-nplz3 in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $GITHUB_SECRET
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Clone Repository to Jenkins Agent)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $GITHUB_SECRET
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ apk add --no-cache git
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/2) Installing libexpat (2.6.2-r0)
(2/2) Installing git (2.40.1-r0)
Executing busybox-1.36.0-r9.trigger
OK: 62 MiB in 81 packages
+ git clone https://****@github.com/PREngineer/Test2
Cloning into 'Test2'...
+ mv Test2/CI Test2/app Test2/autoload.php Test2/composer.json Test2/phpunit.xml Test2/tests /App/
+ rm -R Test2
+ ls -R /App
/App:
CI
app
autoload.php
composer.json
phpunit.xml
tests

/App/CI:
Jenkinsfile

/App/app:
SodaMachine.php

/App/tests:
SodaMachineTest.php
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Run PHP Unit Tests)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ phpunit --log-junit /App/junit.xml --coverage-html /App/results/phpunit/clover --coverage-clover /App/results/phpunit/clover.xml --testdox /App
PHPUnit 10.1.0 by Sebastian Bergmann, Jorge Pabón, and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.1.19

.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 00:00.027, Memory: 8.00 MB

Soda Machine (App\SodaMachine)
 ✔ Can purchase

There was 1 PHPUnit test runner warning:

1) No filter is configured, code coverage will not be processed

WARNINGS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Warnings: 1.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE

Useful Information so far:

In my local machine, I can run PHPUnit in path '.' and everything works properly.
In my K3S cluster, if I run PHPUnit pointing to path '.' it cannot execute the tests or the code coverage.
If my K3S cluster, if I run PHPUnit pointing to path '/App' it can execute the tests but it fails on code coverage.

Seems like the Jenkins agent runs in another path and I am not sure how to have it run everything based on the '/App' directory, where all my code is.
Does anybody have a clue why I am getting this?  Any idea how I can solve it?
Appreciate your time reading and providing feedback!

Answer to Rico's question

In Docker (Local Computer)

/App # env
HOSTNAME=0a66f36d8a94
PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
PHP_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -pie
PHP_CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
PHP_VERSION=8.1.19
GPG_KEYS=<KEYS>
PHP_CPPFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
PHP_ASC_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-8.1.19.tar.xz.asc
PHP_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-8.1.19.tar.xz
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf            dpkg-dev dpkg           file            g++             gcc             libc-dev                make            pkgconf                 re2c
PWD=/App
PHP_SHA256=f42f0e93467415b2d30aa5b7ac825f0079a74207e0033010383cdc1e13657379
/App #


In K3S pod:

JENKINS_HOME=/var/jenkins_home
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.43.0.1:443
JENKINS_SERVICE_PORT_JNLP=50000
CI=true
HOSTNAME=test-105-mcgxj-lnxpd-bjh32
PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php
POD_LABEL=Test_105-mcgxj
RUN_CHANGES_DISPLAY_URL=https://jenkins.techbytetips.com/job/Test/105/display/redirect?page=changes
SHLVL=3
HUDSON_URL=https://jenkins.techbytetips.com/
NODE_LABELS=Test_105-mcgxj test-105-mcgxj-lnxpd-bjh32
HOME=/root
OLDPWD=/App
BUILD_URL=https://jenkins.techbytetips.com/job/Test/105/
JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE=<COOKIE>
PHP_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -pie
PHP_CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
PHP_VERSION=8.1.19
WORKSPACE=/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Test
GPG_KEYS=<KEYS>
JENKINS_SERVICE_PORT_HTTP=8080
PHP_CPPFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
PHP_ASC_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-8.1.19.tar.xz.asc
NODE_NAME=test-105-mcgxj-lnxpd-bjh32
POD_CONTAINER=jenkins-php8-agent
RUN_ARTIFACTS_DISPLAY_URL=https://jenkins.techbytetips.com/job/Test/105/display/redirect?page=artifacts
PHP_URL=https://www.php.net/distributions/php-8.1.19.tar.xz
EXECUTOR_NUMBER=0
STAGE_NAME=Clone Repository to Jenkins Agent
JENKINS_PORT_50000_TCP_ADDR=10.43.105.169
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.43.0.1
BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME=#105
RUN_TESTS_DISPLAY_URL=https://jenkins.techbytetips.com/job/Test/105/display/redirect?page=tests
HUDSON_HOME=/var/jenkins_home
JOB_BASE_NAME=Test
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
JENKINS_SERVICE_HOST=10.43.105.169
JENKINS_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR=10.43.105.169
JENKINS_PORT_50000_TCP_PORT=50000
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
BUILD_ID=105
JENKINS_PORT_50000_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
BUILD_TAG=jenkins-Test-105
JENKINS_PORT_8080_TCP_PORT=8080
JENKINS_URL=https://jenkins.techbytetips.com/
JENKINS_PORT_8080_TCP_PROTO=tcp
JOB_URL=https://jenkins.techbytetips.com/job/Test/
BUILD_NUMBER=105
JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=<COOKIE>
JENKINS_PORT=tcp://10.43.105.169:8080
JENKINS_SERVICE_PORT=8080
RUN_DISPLAY_URL=https://jenkins.techbytetips.com/job/Test/105/display/redirect
HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE=<COOKIE>
GITHUB_SECRET=<SECRET>
JOB_DISPLAY_URL=https://jenkins.techbytetips.com/job/Test/display/redirect
JENKINS_PORT_50000_TCP=tcp://10.43.105.169:50000
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.43.0.1:443
CLASSPATH=
JOB_NAME=Test
PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf        dpkg-dev dpkg       file        g++         gcc         libc-dev        make        pkgconf         re2c
JENKINS_PORT_8080_TCP=tcp://10.43.105.169:8080
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.43.0.1
PWD=/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Test
PHP_SHA256=f42f0e93467415b2d30aa5b7ac825f0079a74207e0033010383cdc1e13657379
WORKSPACE_TMP=/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Test@tmp

Update after Rico's comment and success based on what I learned from it:
Pipeline runs now that I made the following changes to files.
SodaMachine.php:
<?php

namespace App;

class SodaMachine {

  // Variables
  private $cans;

  // Methods

  // Returns the amount of cans in the machine
  public function getCans(){
    return $this->cans;
  }

  // Fill the machine to the specified amount of cans
  public function setCans( $amount ){
    $this->cans = $amount;
  }

  // Processes a can purchase
  public function buyCan(){
    $this->setCans( $this->getCans() - 1 );
  }

}

?>

SodaMachineTest.php:
<?php

// Use the same namespace as the app
namespace App;

require 'app/SodaMachine.php';

/**
 * @covers \App\SodaMachine
*/
class SodaMachineTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase{
  // Variables
  
  // Define an instance of the Soda Machine
  public $sodaMachine;

  // Functions

  // Instantiate the machine (make sure to mark it returns void or PHPUnit complains)
  public function setUp(): void {
    $this->sodaMachine = new SodaMachine();
  }
  
  /**
   * Test the machine functionality
   * @covers \App\SodaMachine::buyCan
  */
  public function testCanPurchase(){
    // Start with 10 cans
    $this->sodaMachine->setCans( 10 );
    // Buy a can
    $this->sodaMachine->buyCan();
    // Validate it processed it right and we have 9 left
    $this->assertEquals( 9, $this->sodaMachine->getCans() );
  }
  
}

?>

phpunit.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Define properties and behavior -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/10.1/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="autoload.php"
         cacheDirectory=".phpunit.cache"
         executionOrder="depends,defects"
         requireCoverageMetadata="true"
         beStrictAboutCoverageMetadata="true"
         beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
         failOnRisky="true"
         failOnWarning="false"
         colors="true"
         stopOnFailure="false">

  <!-- Include locations of the classes -->
  <php>
    <includePath>.</includePath>
    <includePath>app</includePath>
    <includePath>tests</includePath>
  </php>
  
  <!-- Specify the Test Suites -->
  <testsuites>
    <!-- Name and location of the Test Suite to perform -->
    <testsuite name="Soda Machine Tests">
      <!-- Path is relative to the location of this config file -->
      <directory>tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>

  <!-- Specify Test Coverage -->
  <source restrictDeprecations="true" restrictNotices="true" restrictWarnings="true">
    <include>
      <!-- Cover all PHP files in the app folder -->
      <!-- Path is relative to the location of this config file -->
      <directory suffix=".php">app</directory>
    </include>
  </source>
  
</phpunit>

autoload.php:
<?php

// autoload.php

spl_autoload_register( function( $class ){

    // Convert the class name to a file path
    $classPath = str_replace( '\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class ) . '.php';

    // Check if the file exists
    if( file_exists($classPath) ){
        require_once $classPath;
    }
  }
);

?>

Jenkinsfile:
// Start the Pipeline
pipeline {
  // Define the agent where it will run
  agent {
    // kubernetes = kubernetes cloud in Jenkins
    kubernetes { 
// Define the pod template, what will the pods be, and resources for them
yaml '''
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: jenkins-php8-agent
    image: prengineer/jenkins-agent-php-8.1:ARM64
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command:
    - sleep
    args:
    - 1d
  restartPolicy: Never
'''
    }
  }
  
  // Define GitHub credentials to use
  environment {
    GITHUB_SECRET = credentials('gh-prengineer')
  }
  // Start declaring the stages of the pipeline
  stages { 
    // Stage #1 - Clone the repository
    stage('Clone Repository to Jenkins Agent') {
      steps {
        container('jenkins-php8-agent') {
          withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'gh-prengineer', variable: 'GITHUB_SECRET')]) {
            sh '''
              # Install Git (if not already installed)
              apk add --no-cache git
              
              # Clone using git
              git clone https://${GITHUB_SECRET}@github.com/PREngineer/Test2
              
              # Clean up directory
              mv Test2/* .
              rm -R Test2
              ls -R .
            '''
          }
        }
      }
    }
    // Stage #2 - Build the Docker image using Kaniko and push to registry
    stage('Run PHP Unit Tests') {
      steps {
        container('jenkins-php8-agent') {
          sh 'phpunit --log-junit results/phpunit/junit.xml --coverage-html results/phpunit/clover --coverage-clover results/phpunit/clover.xml --testdox .'
          junit 'results/phpunit/*.xml'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Result of last run:
Started by user Jorge Pabón
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Created Pod: K3S devops-tools/test-111-9sm10-hsmsh-n68t4
Agent test-111-9sm10-hsmsh-n68t4 is provisioned from template Test_111-9sm10-hsmsh
---
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
  annotations:
    buildUrl: "http://jenkins.devops-tools.svc.cluster.local:8080/job/Test/111/"
    runUrl: "job/Test/111/"
  labels:
    jenkins: "agent"
    jenkins/label-digest: "c122ab023cc36f7337879291ef9c1e1413e98de8"
    jenkins/label: "Test_111-9sm10"
  name: "test-111-9sm10-hsmsh-n68t4"
  namespace: "devops-tools"
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - "1d"
    command:
    - "sleep"
    image: "prengineer/jenkins-agent-php-8.1:ARM64"
    imagePullPolicy: "Always"
    name: "jenkins-php8-agent"
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
  - env:
    - name: "JENKINS_SECRET"
      value: "********"
    - name: "JENKINS_TUNNEL"
      value: "jenkins.devops-tools.svc.cluster.local:50000"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_NAME"
      value: "test-111-9sm10-hsmsh-n68t4"
    - name: "JENKINS_NAME"
      value: "test-111-9sm10-hsmsh-n68t4"
    - name: "JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR"
      value: "/home/jenkins/agent"
    - name: "JENKINS_URL"
      value: "http://jenkins.devops-tools.svc.cluster.local:8080/"
    image: "jenkins/inbound-agent:3206.vb_15dcf73f6a_9-2"
    name: "jnlp"
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "256Mi"
        cpu: "100m"
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: "linux"
  restartPolicy: "Never"
  volumes:
  - emptyDir:
      medium: ""
    name: "workspace-volume"

Running on test-111-9sm10-hsmsh-n68t4 in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $GITHUB_SECRET
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Clone Repository to Jenkins Agent)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $GITHUB_SECRET
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ apk add --no-cache git
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/2) Installing libexpat (2.6.2-r0)
(2/2) Installing git (2.40.1-r0)
Executing busybox-1.36.0-r9.trigger
OK: 62 MiB in 81 packages
+ git clone https://****@github.com/PREngineer/Test2
Cloning into 'Test2'...
+ mv Test2/CI Test2/app Test2/autoload.php Test2/composer.json Test2/phpunit.xml Test2/tests .
+ rm -R Test2
+ ls -R .
.:
CI
app
autoload.php
composer.json
phpunit.xml
tests

./CI:
Jenkinsfile

./app:
SodaMachine.php

./tests:
SodaMachineTest.php
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Run PHP Unit Tests)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ phpunit --log-junit results/phpunit/junit.xml --coverage-html results/phpunit/clover --coverage-clover results/phpunit/clover.xml --testdox .
PHPUnit 10.1.0 by Sebastian Bergmann, Jorge Pabón, and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.1.19 with Xdebug 3.3.2
Configuration: /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Test/phpunit.xml

.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 00:00.259, Memory: 12.00 MB

Soda Machine (App\SodaMachine)
 ✔ Can purchase

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... done [00:00.010]

Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done [00:00.034]
[Pipeline] junit
Recording test results
[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS

Not sure if I have to make changes to the autoload.php file or somewhere else so that I don't have to require SodaMachine.php in SodaMachineTest.php.

It looks like just related to environment.  Can you compare the output of env on both instances - docker and jenkins?

Hi @Rico, I have added the answer to your question and removed unnecessary information.
Looks like this might be the problem and I have no clue how to fix it:
PWD=/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Test

@Rico, thanks a lot!  That helped me a bit and now at least everything is running.
The only thing that I don't understand at this point is why I still need to require the class and it just doesn't work with the namespace and autoloader.
I'm adding the updated files for review.

You first clone and then you already test. The pipeline is missing a build step. You get the  test classes "autoloaded" because the test-runner (PHPUnit) loads them before running. Therefore they don't require autoloading. However as you don't build you don't have the  autoloader from composer and henceforth Phpunit did complain. Have your autoloader in that file (instead of requires) or even better have a build step in your pipeline before test that does composer install as that will create the vendor/autoload.php file (standard). Use the bootstrap setting to point to that file if unused.

Solution
Issue
The Jenkins agent was running using its workspace directory.  I couldn't use the /App directory, that I had specified, to hold the repository; which was supposed to be the container's WORKDIR.
On the Autoload feature... I have an autoload that successfully loads the test files however, the classes that are needed to be loaded by the test cases have to be added directly in there because an autoload doesn't work well due to the same issue with the workspace directory.
Solution

Re-organize the Jenkinsfile to use the current directory for everything.
Require the classes directly in the test cases.

Result
Now the test cases run perfectly and I even managed to get the Clover Reporting working perfectly in Jenkins.
Final file structure:
Test
 | app
    |  SodaMachine.php
 | CI
    |  Jenkinsfile
 | tests
    |  SodaMachineTest.php
 | autoload.php
 | phpunit.xml

Final files:
SodaMachine.php:
<?php

// Use the namespace app to organize classes
namespace App;

class SodaMachine {

  // Variables
  private $cans;

  // Methods

  // Returns the amount of cans in the machine
  public function getCans(){
    return $this->cans;
  }

  // Fill the machine to the specified amount of cans
  public function setCans( $amount ){
    $this->cans = $amount;
  }

  // Processes a can purchase
  public function buyCan(){
    $this->setCans( $this->getCans() - 1 );
  }

}

?>

Jenkinsfile:
// Start the Pipeline
pipeline {

  // Define the agent where it will run
  agent {

    // kubernetes = kubernetes cloud in Jenkins
    kubernetes { 

      // Define the pod template, what will the pods be, and resources for them
      yaml '''
      kind: Pod
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: jenkins-php8-agent
          image: prengineer/jenkins-agent-php-8.1:ARM64
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command:
          - sleep
          args:
          - 1d
        restartPolicy: Never
      '''

    }

  }
  
  // Define GitHub credentials to use
  environment {
    GITHUB_SECRET = credentials('gh-prengineer')
  }

  // Start declaring the stages of the pipeline
  stages { 

    // Stage #1 - Clone the repository
    stage('Clone Repository to Jenkins Agent') {
      steps {
        // Specify the container where the stage will run
        container('jenkins-php8-agent') {
          // Make sure to pass GitHub credentials to clone
          withCredentials( [ string(credentialsId: 'gh-prengineer', variable: 'GITHUB_SECRET') ] ) {
            // Execute shell commands
            sh '''
              # Install Git (if not already installed)
              apk add --no-cache git
              
              # Clone using git
              git clone https://${GITHUB_SECRET}@github.com/PREngineer/Test
              
              # Clean up directory by removing the repo folder
              mv Test/* .
              rm -R Test
            '''
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // Stage #2 - Run the PHPUnit tests
    stage('Run PHP Unit Tests') {
      steps {
        // Specify the container where the stage will run
        container('jenkins-php8-agent') {
          // Execute PHPUnit
          sh 'phpunit --log-junit results/phpunit/junit.xml --coverage-html results/phpunit/clover --coverage-clover results/phpunit/clover/clover.xml --testdox .'
          // Have Jenins process the PHPUnit results
          junit 'results/phpunit/*.xml'
        }
      }
    }

    // Stage #3 - Publish Code Coverage Report
    stage('Publish Code Coverage Report') {
      steps {
        // Specify the container where the stage will run
        container('jenkins-php8-agent') {
          // Define how the Clover Plugin should process the code coverage results
          clover(
            // Where the HTML and XML reports are located
            cloverReportDir: 'results/phpunit/clover', cloverReportFileName: 'clover.xml',
            // Define the health targets for Clover
            // Optional, default is: method=70, conditional=80, statement=80
            healthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 70, conditionalCoverage: 70, statementCoverage: 70],
            // Optional, default is none
            unhealthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 50, conditionalCoverage: 50, statementCoverage: 50],
            // Optional, default is none
            failingTarget: [methodCoverage: 0, conditionalCoverage: 0, statementCoverage: 0]
          )
        }
      }
    }

  }
  
}

SodaMachineTest.php:
<?php

// Use the same namespace as the app
namespace App;

// Make sure we have access to the class that we are testing
require 'app/SodaMachine.php';

/**
 * @covers \App\SodaMachine
*/
class SodaMachineTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase{
  // Variables
  
  // Define an instance of the Soda Machine
  public $sodaMachine;

  // Functions

  // Instantiate the machine (make sure to mark it returns void or PHPUnit complains)
  public function setUp(): void {
    $this->sodaMachine = new SodaMachine();
  }
  
  /**
   * Test the machine functionality
   * @covers \App\SodaMachine::buyCan
  */
  public function testCanPurchase(){
    // Start with 10 cans
    $this->sodaMachine->setCans( 10 );
    // Buy a can
    $this->sodaMachine->buyCan();
    // Validate it processed it right and we have 9 left
    $this->assertEquals( 9, $this->sodaMachine->getCans() );
  }
  
}

?>

autoload.php:
<?php

// autoload.php

spl_autoload_register( function( $class ){

    // Convert the class name to a file path
    $classPath = str_replace( '\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class ) . '.php';

    // Check if the file exists
    if( file_exists($classPath) ){
        require_once $classPath;
    }
  }
);

?>

phpunit.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Define properties and behavior -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/10.1/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="autoload.php"
         cacheDirectory=".phpunit.cache"
         executionOrder="depends,defects"
         requireCoverageMetadata="true"
         beStrictAboutCoverageMetadata="true"
         beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
         failOnRisky="true"
         failOnWarning="false"
         colors="true"
         stopOnFailure="false">

  <!-- Include locations of the classes -->
  <php>
    <includePath>.</includePath>
    <includePath>app</includePath>
    <includePath>tests</includePath>
  </php>
  
  <!-- Specify the Test Suites -->
  <testsuites>
    <!-- Name and location of the Test Suite to perform -->
    <testsuite name="Soda Machine Tests">
      <!-- Path is relative to the location of this config file -->
      <directory>tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>

  <!-- Specify Test Coverage -->
  <source restrictDeprecations="true" restrictNotices="true" restrictWarnings="true">
    <include>
      <!-- Cover all PHP files in the app folder -->
      <!-- Path is relative to the location of this config file -->
      <directory suffix=".php">app</directory>
    </include>
  </source>
  
</phpunit>

